# Make proportional stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame `example` with two variables V1 and V2, both are dummy variables. I want to create a stacked proportional graph with V1 as x axis.

I tried the following, but the graph is not showing up:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr) 
library(dplyr)

example<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1),c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)))
class(example$V1)
class(example$V2)

ce = ddply(example, "V1", mutate, percent_v2 = sum(V2)/length(V2) * 100)
ggplot(ce, aes(x=V1, y=percent_v2, fill=V2),geom_bar(stat='identity'))
```

I thought maybe `fill=V2` is wrong because both V1 and V2 are integers, so I tried `as.character(V2)` instead, but this did not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 ggplot(ce, aes(x=V1, y=percent_v2, fill=V2))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

## Addition:

[image]

```
    V1 V2 percent_v2
 1  0  0         20
 2  0  1         20
 3  0  0         20
 4  0  0         20
 5  0  0         20
 6  1  1         50
 7  1  0         50
 8  1  0         50
 9  1  1         50
```

Comment: I tried ggplot(ce, aes(x=V1, y=percent_v2, fill=as.character(V2)))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
 and this looks similar to what I want but shouldn't both have 100 as max ylim? i don't know why i get 200 maxlim for when v1=1

Comment: I added the data and plot above. For the case when V1==0 your percent_v2 sums up to 100 . But this is not the case for V1==1 (you have 50% 4 times)